# Adding memory to load_qa_chain

Tags: python-3.x, memory, langchain

How can I add memory to

```
load_qa_chain memory_3 =  ConversationBufferMemory() 
chain_qa = load_qa_chain(llm = local_llm, # memory = memory_3,# prompt = prompt_inv_o1,chain_type="stuff") 
query = "What is the Invoice Number and date" 
docs = db.similarity_search(query) 
result= chain_qa.run(input_documents = docsquestion = query,#memory = memory_3 # question=query)print(result)
```

Comment: This is not human-readable at all. Please follow how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)